# Spark RDD: Using collect() at range() object

Tags: python, apache-spark, range, collect

I want to convert the numbers 0 to 99 into a RDD.

```
rd1 = range(1, 100)
test = sc.parallelize(rd1)
```

When I use the collect() function...

```
print(test.collect())
```

...I receive the following error message:

```
PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.
```

According to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html) documentary, it's supposed to work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has the same problem. I could solve it by selecting only the lines I want to execute.

I think that other scripts that ran parallel led to the error.